# File's Owner Icon

Tags: xcode4.3

I have spent way too much time looking for the files owner icon to click-drag to a text field to assign a variable to that field. Then it hit me that the icon only shows on nib files. Not storyboards. So what is the option to assign a variable to a text field, hard coding?  What I am trying to do is show the continuous coords for current location in two text fields on my home screen and update as they move. I have all of that coding done just haven't been able to assign the variable to the field. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's just slightly different in storyboards, you drag to the view controller instead of files owner.
[image]