# Missing the File's Owner item

Tags: xcode4.3, file-ownership

i try to understand how i can show my textfield over the keyboard and do an tutorial. this is an older Version than my SDK 5.1. Now I try to do this : "In Interface Builder, right-click on each Text Field view and connect the delegate outlet to the File's Owner item." I can't find the File'S Owner Item. 
Best regards 
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably need some more information - and I may be answering the wrong question... but on the assumption that you're using Xcode 4.3 and have noticed the same issue as me:

- NIB (.xib) files in the built-in Interface Builder will have File's Owners
- Storyboard (.storyboard) files won't

Here's how it looks for a .xib with a standard appDelegate.m UIApplication object: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxMjC.png

The following property has been defined in appDelegate.h to allow the UIButton to be connected.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Test;
```

You should probably look at storyboards, if you haven't already. The following answer gives a good view of how to connect outlets and actions to ViewControllers when using a storyboard.

[File's Owner Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807492/files-owner-icon)